# Was the Monks storyline a Brexit metaphor?

Tags: doctor-who, inspiration

TV Tropes [claims](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ValuesResonance) that the Monks storyline on *Doctor Who* (seen in "The Pyramid at the End of the World," etc.) is an allegory for Brexit:

> ...the actual Who Brexit allegory story (the Monks trilogy) is somewhat less on-the-nose

A brief search doesn't seem to turn up this connection, however, and I don't see the thematic analogy. For example, there's no exit from any organization—if anything, Earth enters an organization. There's a theme of revisionist history, but it's very broad. And so forth. But perhaps the themes are more subtle.

**Is there any evidence that the Monks storyline was intended as an allegory or metaphor for Brexit?**

Comment: The arc as a whole doesn't seem to fit, so probably down to *The Lie of the Land* with, as you said, revisionist history, and the conning of the public, but since it was honestly a pretty silly episode, I will avoid the headache of poorly attempted political metaphor by not caring.

Comment: Doubtful, it was filmed 4 months after the vote. Time enough, true, but kind of a quick turnaround if so.

Comment: To the close voters, we have a whole tag for what inspired a work, and this is often objectively answerable. Plus, I have a citation for notability, so I didn’t just make this up off the top of my head.